# Evaluate significance for three different groups not normal distributed with different n

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, kruskal-wallis-test, tukey-hsd-test

I have a group with three different treatments. One group gets shown 0 Tags, 4 and 7. N's are different in the range of 80-100 and data does not follow a normal distribution.

I would also like to compare 0 to 4, 0 to 7 and 4 to 7

How can I evaluate my data for statistical significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has the structure of a one-way anova with three groups. Since the distributions are not normal, you can use some robust or non-parametric approach.  See for instance [non-parametric alternatives to anova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398217/non-parametric-alternatives-to-anova)  and [Can I trust ANOVA results for a non-normally distributed DV?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/can-i-trust-anova-results-for-a-non-normally-distributed-dv/5946#5946).

But you seem to be interested in post-hoc analysis, so see [Kruskal-Wallis and post-hoc analysis in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139222/kruskal-wallis-and-post-hoc-analysis-in-r)